# R command rmcorr CI bootstrap argument not working?

Tags: r, correlation, statistics-bootstrap, longitudinal

Tried using the example data provided by the package and specified the use of CI bootstrap:

```
rmcorr(Subject, PaCO2, pH, bland1995, CI.level=0.95, CIs=c("analytic","bootstrap"), nreps=100,bstrap.out=T)
```

But the CI with and without using bootstrapping are the same? why is that? is there anything wrong with the argument above?

Thank you.

Tried to use the command to get bootstrap CI but not success.

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: Not sure how to use dput but the reproducible data is within the package rmcorr